# Cannot connect to Joomla DB but can access administrator panel

Tags: mysql, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a new Joomla (2.5) site that has been developed on a different host/server which is working fine. I am trying to get it moved onto my host.

I have been through the normal process, files uploaded via FTP, database exported and imported using PHPmyadmin (I can provide the version of PHPmyadmin it has been exported from is an earlier version if this makes a difference?) Finally the `configuration.php` file has been edited to include the correct host, db, user and password information.

When I try to navigate to the website, I get the following error:

```
500 - JDatabase::getInstance: Could not connect to database
joomla.library: 2 - Could not connect to MySQL.
```

Though I can navigate to the /administrator page and browser the back end / control panel and pages of the website.

Turning on the debug function, I get the following:

```
JDatabase::getInstance: Could not connect to database
joomla.library: 2 - Could not connect to MySQL.

Call stack
#   Function    Location
1   JSite->render() JROOT/index.php:48
2   JDocumentHTML->render() JROOT/includes/application.php:261
3   JDocumentHTML->_renderTemplate()    JROOT/libraries/joomla/document     /html/html.php:433
4   JDocumentHTML->getBuffer()  JROOT/libraries/joomla/document/html/html.php:655
5   JDocumentRendererModules->render()  JROOT/libraries/joomla/document    /html/html.php:371
6   JDocumentRendererModule->render()   JROOT/libraries/joomla/document    /html/renderer/modules.php:39
7   JModuleHelper::renderModule()   JROOT/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer    /module.php:106
8   include()   JROOT/libraries/joomla/application/module/helper.php:175
9   JError::raiseError()    JROOT/modules/mod_wpposts/mod_wpposts.php:31
10  JError::raise() JROOT/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:251
```

I am not a developer, and do not understand any of the above! I have moved / copied another couple of sites without issue, but these were on the same host/server.

Comment: "Could not connect to MySQL" suggests the db username/password are incorrect. Or, maybe the web server cannot see the database - is the database on a different server to the web server?

Comment: the db user and password are correct, I have also tried setting up a completely new db and repeating the process, same issues. The web server and db server are the same, so 'localhost' is used. thanks

Comment: Can you `ssh` to the web server and run the `mysql` console from there, using the credentials you believe to be correct? Maybe the Joomla admin page is protected by htaccess credentials rather than connecting via a database (I don't know Joomla - just guessing)?

Comment: Apologies, but i'm not sure what you mean by this? "ssh to the web server and run the mysql console from there"

Comment: Secure telnet. It's beyond the scope of this site to teach you it, but it's a way to connect to the console of the (Linux?) web server and type commands in remotely. You connect using an IP, a username and a password - often the same as your FTP credentials. Putty is a great client to use, if you're on Windows locally.

Comment: (You didn't answer my question about whether the database was on the same server, btw).

Comment: Sorry, you were so quick to answer, I was editing my comment! Yes it is on the same server. It could be too much for my lack of knowledge, but only differences to what I've done with another site, is the fact its moving from one host/db to another. I previously copied a site to a subdomain for test purposes using the same process without issues.

Comment: OK, I'm pretty sure that your connection credentials are wrong (could they be different for the frontend?). Double-check the hostname (it could require "127.0.0.1" rather than "localhost"), the username and password (including case sensitivity) and the port (it may be non-standard). Also, have a look at `JROOT/libraries/joomla/application/module/helper.php` in line 175 where the exception appears to be thrown - you could try editing your local copy to _temporarily_ include some `echo $username` statements, and FTP it up.

Comment: I may have solved it. There was a module created to include wordpress for a news function (pointing to a seperate db) disabling this means the site will now load. There are a few other issues on the backend, but I'll have to work these out separately. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error log listed above I would think that your issue is with the module "wpposts".

Try to unpublish that module from the site. You probably forgot to move the Wordpress database and now the module that is supposed to display "latest posts" or similar is failing and bringing down the site.

Comment: Søren this was exactly this issue, and doing what you suggested worked. Thanks for your advice.